# Where can I find models in .od format?

Tags: object, 3d, format, target, vuforia

I'm doing my project in Unity 3d with Vuforia library. So i wanted to make my target as 3d object but it takes only .od format objects. I couldn't find .od format objects in the internet! Maybe somebody knows how to convert .obj to .od? or sources where i can find out .od objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .od objects are created with Vuforia Object Scanner.

The Vuforia Object Scanner is an android application for 3d scanning.
The app can only be installed by download on this link: 
https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/tool

This is the tutorial link of how to use the app:
https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Vuforia-Object-Scanner-Users-Guide

I think these objects are only generated by this app.

About converting obj to od, take a look at this discussion: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/object-recognition/3d-print-obj-files-convert-od

According to that discussion, there is no way to convert obj to od.